# Transcation updateFunction parameter is null

Tags: firebase

I can't get transaction to work and need some help

I created the following db structure using the FB app dashboard:
  flickering-heat-528
    test
      settings: "hello"

I can see in the dashboard that the data is there:

[image]

I then do:

```
var settingsRef=new Firebase('https://flickering-heat-528.firebaseio.com/test/settings');

settingsRef.transaction(function(json) {
    alert(json);
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
}, true);
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ka38jLbm/)

But the alert is always 'null' why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction callbacks in Firebase may fire multiple times. To understand why that is, let's see how this operation may be executed.

Let's start with this logic: if the current value is null, you want it to become "byebye".

```
settingsRef.transaction(function(current) {
    if (!current) {
       return "byebye";
    }
    return current;
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
}, true);
```

The Firebase client doesn't yet know the value of your `settings` node, so it invokes your transaction with an assumption: that the current value is `null`. It then sends the combination of the value if gave to you and the value you returned to the Firebase server.

The Firebase server compares the current value in the database (`"hello"`) against the value it provided to you and decides they don't match (`"hello" <> null`). So it sends the current value (`"hello"`) back to the client.

The Firebase client invokes your callback again. This time it passes in the value it heard from the server (`"hello"`):

```
settingsRef.transaction(function(current) {
    if (!current) {
       return "byebye";
    }
    return current + "!";
}, function(error, committed, snapshot) {
}, true);
```

So now your function returns `"hello!"`. Firebase again sends the value it gave you and the value you returned to the server: `"hello"` and `"hello!"`. The server does the same comparison as before and *if the value in the database is still `"hello"`* it sets the new value you specified `"hello!"`.

This is called a compare-and-set operation and explains why your callback may be called multiple times.

Comment: thx Frank ! so does that mean updateFunc is always first called with null ? if yes isn't that first call useless and can it be voided ?